# how to write the value() method?

Tags: java

I'm writing an ArithmeticOperation class and the value() method needs to combine the left operand, operation, and right operand. Could anyone write it in commons?

ArithmeticOperation: The ArithmeticOperation represents an arithmetic operation between two values. The ArithmeticOperation type should contain the following enum type to represent the possible operations for the language (you are free to add additional operators if you wish):

public enum Operator { Add, Sub, Mult, Div, Rem; }
The operators represent the +, -, *, /, and % operations.
An ArithmeticOperation type instance should be created with three arguments: an operation that is from the above Operator enum type, and two expressions that represent the left operand expression and the right operand expression. The type should allow any language structure that has an int/Integer value to be a possible expression. The ArithmeticOperation type should have the following methods:

value: takes a state as input and returns the int/Integer value that is the result of applying the operation to the values of each of the operand expressions. The state should be used to get the values of the expressions.
toString: should return a string that first contains a string representation of the left operand followed by a space, a string representation of the operator, a space, and the string representation of the right operand.

```
public interface Operation {
   public enum Operator { Add, Sub, Mult, Div, Rem; }
}

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ArithmeticOperation <I> implements Operation{
     ArithmeticOperation <Integer> leftoperand = new 
ArithmeticOperation <Integer>();
     ArithmeticOperation <Operator> operation = new 
ArithmeticOperation <Operator>();
     ArithmeticOperation <Integer> rightoperand = new 
ArithmeticOperation <Integer>(); 


    public Integer value(State s){
           return leftoperand+operation+rightoperand;
     }

     public String toString(){
          return "("+leftoperand+" , "+operation+", 
"+rightoperand+")";

     }    

}




1 error found:
File: /Users/a13875810600/Desktop/ArithmeticOperation.java  [line: 
11]
Error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
  first type:  ArithmeticOperation<java.lang.Integer>
  second type: ArithmeticOperation<Operation.Operator>
```

I am wondering to know how to add the Integer type and the Operator type now. It's really worth to think for a long time.

Comment: Also, If I do not make sense in some part, please directly writes in comment which may help me to make some improvements in this question.

Comment: Your `value` function doesnt make sense. How can you use '+' sign on `Integer` and `Operator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it would be:

```
public Integer value(State s){
    switch (operation) {
        case Add:
            return leftoperand.value(s) + rightoperand.value(s);
        case Sub:
            return leftoperand.value(s) - rightoperand.value(s);
        case Mul:
            return leftoperand.value(s) * rightoperand.value(s);
        case Div:
            return leftoperand.value(s) / rightoperand.value(s);
        case Rem:
            return leftoperand.value(s) % rightoperand.value(s);
    }
}
```